# No such file or directory when deploying a shinyapp

Tags: shiny, shinyapps

I've built a shiny app that works perfectly, but I'm not being succesful at deploying it.

When I deploy it to the shinyapps.io it returns a message error related to the .csv file I'm using.

My working directory is "C:/Users/F0379/Desktop/Exterior" and I'm importing the file with

`prop_usd <- read.csv("./propostas_usd.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")`

When I run the app it works, the problem is when I deploy it.

The error message is

> Warning in file(file, "rt") : cannot open file './propostas_usd.csv': No such file or directory

It seems something simple to solve, but I got stuck in it.

Comment: make sure your file is where `server.R` is and do not use `setwd()`. Also remove the `./` and use `read.csv("propostas_usd.csv"...`

Comment: I removed the ```./ ``` and didn't use ```setwd()```, but I'm not sure of the first part. I don't have a file for the ```server.R```, both ```server.R``` and ```Ui.R``` are in the same ```app.R```file, in the same directory as the ```.csv``` file

Comment: I'm now getting a different error message: **error in value[[3L]](cond) : invalide string multibyte 1**